# Get an index from an index

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm taking an online course which corrects code using a bot.
The assignment is to:

- Create a variable `a`
- All values of `a` is of type `a`
- `a[a[0]] + a[1] === 3`
- `a[1] === 10`
- `a.length === 3`

This is my code so far:

```
let a = [0,1,2]
a[a[0]] + a[1] === 30
a[1] = 10
a[0] = 20

a.length === 3

console.log(a, a[a[0]], a[a[0]] + a[1])
```

The output from the bot:

```
file.js
    ✓ exists
    ✓ is valid JavaScript
    ✓ defines a of the type Array
    ✓ defines a such that a.length evaluates to 3
    1) defines a such that a[a[0]] + a[1] === 30 evaluates to true
    ✓ defines a such that a[1] === 10 evaluates to true
```

What am I missing? How do I make so that `a[a[0]] + a[1] === 30` evaluates to true?

Answer (score 0):

Since `a[1]` is 10, you need `a[a[0]] + 10 === 30`, or `a[a[0]] === 20`. Put into `[0]` the only other index available (`[2]`) so that accessing that index of the array gives 20:

```js
const a = [2, 10, 20];
console.log(
  a.length,
  a[a[0]] + a[1],
  a[1]
);
```

```
// Simplifying:
a[a[0]] + a[1]
a[a[0]] + 10
a[2] + 10
20 + 10
30
```

Answer (score 0):

okay, so begin with what you know: `a[1] === 10` and `a.length = 3`. that leaves you with following:

```
[x, 10, y]
```

now your `a[0] = x`, so for `a[a[0]] + a[1] = 30` you can say `a[x] + a[1] = 30`. the only spot left in your array is the third (index 2). that way, you know, that `x = a[0] = 2` (because `a[2] = y`)

```
[2, 10, y]
```

now to calculate you just solve for it

```
a[a[0]] + a[1] = 30
a[x] + a[1] = 30
a[2] + a[1] = 30
a[2] + 10 = 30
a[2] = 20
```

so

```
[2, 10, 20]
```

```js
const a = [2, 10, 20];

console.log(`a[1] = ${a[1]}`);

console.log(`a[a[0]] + a[1] = ${a[a[0]] + a[1]}`);

console.log(`a[2] = ${a[2]}`);

console.log(`a.length = ${a.length}`);
```